# How to make a program run at startup using python

Tags: python-3.x

I know their is the main startup folder in Windows and you can add your program to the startup registry but I wan't a way to add a program to the startup without having to have admin rights, is their a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to add files to folder you require the permissions to access it. If python has full access however you could write your file to the location using Python.
You will likely need to enable hidden folders to find the startup folder. You can do this in control panel -> Appearance and Personalization -> Folder options -> Show hidden files and folders, or optionally you can try to enter it into the path bar of file explorer. An optional thing to do is to look into the startup folder, and see if there is any shortcuts. If you can access the file at the end of any shortcuts you can replace it with an executable running your program. There is very few ways around permissions, but I hope I helped. Btw, this should be tagged as a windows issue.